# php and aspx with one log in?

Tags: php, asp.net, session, logging, authentication

I have two web sites: one built with aspx and the other built with php.
Both apps have a log in system. I need it so that the user can log in to the php site and when they visit the aspx site they continue being logged in and vice versa. So basically a log in that works for both different sites. How do I develop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three thoughts come to mind:

1. .NET typically stores login in a cookie, you could update the forms auth to save a cookie for your other site and update the other site to do the same.  Then have each site look for the cookie.
2. Save your sessions in a database and then have each site hit the same sessions database.
3. Use something like memcache to save sessions and have each site read from there.

Comment: How would I accomplish no. 2?

Comment: Are you using a framework of any sorts?  Some of them already support it.

Comment: Otherwise you would have to update the login process to write to a database table that would have to be check upon visit to the other site for an active session and then auto log them in.  You would also then need a script to clear old sessions, e.g. inactive for 20 minutes.

Comment: No framework from php. I think .net for aspx. Would the session parameters between aspx and php be compatible?

Comment: You would probably need to write some logic to make them.

Comment: Could I create a web service and centralize the authentication system like an external database which authenticates each site?

Comment: That would work.  You would still need to track active logins and do a check on the other site and clear inactive.  Perhaps using an existing 3rd party login would work better like FB, OpenID, etc... the unique ID from those systems would simply be tied to the user in your existing DBs and then they wouldn't need to relogin.